# is there a way assign and call variables in a SKSpriteNode?

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, skspritenode

i am trying to create a game where the user touches a ball and it adds to their score if they touch the ball with the right number on it.

i placed a label on the ball to display the ball number.

when the user presses on the ball, i want it to check the label on the ball and compare it to a variable to see if they match.

i have tried to call the value of myLabel.text, but xcode tells me it is not valid.

what is the best way to store a variable into a SKSpriteNode so it can be compared when the user presses on the SKSpriteNode.

thanks.

here is my code -->

```
func createBallNode(ballNumber: Int) -> SKSpriteNode{
    //set up a ball
    let ball = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "ballimage.png")
    ball.size = CGSize(width:200, height:200)
    ball.name = "ballSpriteNode"
    ball.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOf: ball.frame.size)
    ball.physicsBody?.usesPreciseCollisionDetection = true

    let myLabel = SKLabelNode(fontNamed:"Helvetica")
    myLabel.text = String(ballNumber)
    myLabel.name = "myLabel"
    myLabel.fontSize = 80
    myLabel.fontColor = UIColor.black
    myLabel.position = CGPoint.zero

    ball.addChild(myLabel)
    return ball
}

override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    let touch:UITouch = touches.first!
    let positionInScene = touch.location(in: self)
    let touchedNode = self.atPoint(positionInScene)

    //???

}
```

Comment: Use the userData property.

Comment: thanks, i got it to work with userData

ball.userData = NSMutableDictionary()
ball.userData?.setValue(Int(ballNumber), forKey:”ballNumberKey”)

//and to see it when it is touched

let x = (touchedNode.userData?.value(forKey: “ballNumberKey”)) as! Int
print(x)

Answer (score 0):

Either find the child label node using `childNode(withName:)`, or just change the node name `ball.name = "String(ballNumber)"` and check the node you may have touched

```
if let touchedNode = touchedNode, touchedNode.name == correctNumber {
    //whatever
}
```

Comment: thanks, i ended up using .userData so i could store integers in the SKSpriteNode